# When interpret awk as a command or a programming language?

Tags: awk

I know that `awk` is a script programming language, but sometimes I get confused about when I interpret as command or as a program.

**Eg. 1** - *Here I interpret as a command*:

```
awk '{print $2}' file.txt
```

**Eg. 2** - *Here I interpret as a awk program*:

```
awk 'BEGIN      {skip = 0} \
        skip == 0  {if (NF == 0) 
                     {skip = 1}  \
                    else 
                     {print};  \
                    next} \
        skip == 1  {print; \
                    skip = 0; \
                    next}'
```

*Taken from [here](http://www.vectorsite.net/tsawk_3.html).*

The questions are:

1. When awk need be interpreted as a command?
2. When awk is a program?
3. There's a problem call my first example as a `awk` command?

Something like:

```
awk '{print $2}' file.txt | awk '{FS=" "} {print 4}'
```

means that `awk` programs can communicate using pipes?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make a lot of sense. Most commands are programs (with notable exceptions); most programs are commands. `awk`, like `cat` and `ls`, is both a command and a program. The `awk` program/command is an interpreter for a language which, apparently, is called "AWK". The string following the `awk` command -- even if it's as little as `{print $2}` -- is an AWK program. If you say `awk -f foo`, then the file `foo` (or, arguably, its content) is an AWK program. And yes, just like (most) other commands/programs, `awk` processes can have their I/O redirected to files and pipes.

Answer (score 4):

`awk` has two modes of invocation one is with a program text on the command line and the other with a program from a file. This is stated in the synopsis of the awk man page (this one from mawk on Ubuntu 12.04):

```
   mawk  [-W  option] [-F value] [-v var=value] [--] 'program text' [file
   ...]
   mawk [-W option] [-F value]  [-v  var=value]  [-f  program-file]  [--]
   [file ...]
```

Whether to call the first form a program or not depends on the definition of program you want use. I would say both forms involve programs, whereby on the first the program is specified as a commandline argument. Both of your examples to be of the first form, as neither involves the `-f` option. That the  second example has a multiline commandline argument is, with respect to this, irrelevant.

This is not unique to `awk`. e.g. python by defaults interprets a commandline argument as a program name, but with the `-c` option allows you to specify a program on the commandline (i.e. the default is the other way around from `awk`).

Independent of that is the communication using pipes. That is taken care of by the shell syntax and the OS, the only thing your script needs to do is write to stdout, reps. read from stdin. So yes `awk` programs can communicate over pipes.

Comment: Thanks @Anthon (including the edition). Growing and learning.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, when you call [awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), you refer to the interpreter, not the language. The language is called [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK).

`awk` (or `mawk`, `nawk`) is only utility, which will execute programs written in `AWK` programming language.

As POSIX defined, [awk program](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_05) is:

> program
>
> If no -f option is specified, the first operand to awk shall be the
>   text of the awk program. The application shall supply the program
>   operand as a single argument to awk. If the text does not end in a
>   , awk shall interpret the text as if it did.

So if you don't use `-f` option, you can consider two of your examples as awk program.